# getting deleted row in room database android

Tags: android, database, fragment, android-room

I am using room database. In my activity I have deleted one row from my room database then I go back to previous activity where I am using fragments. in first fragment when i get the list from room database I am getting the deleted row.

Comment: Post your code!

Answer (score 1):

Your fragment is probably caching the data instead of taking it from the database each time the fragment is shown. You should paste the code of your fragment to enlighten the situation a bit.